# How to make a box same size?

Tags: html, css

I need two of my main buttons to have the same sizes, I'm still new to web development so I have no clue.
I currently have the following HTML and CSS for the index.html

```
<body>
<div>
    <img src="img/projectfly-logo.svg">
    <p class="center">We're upgrading!</p>
    <div class="center">
        <a href="#"><h1 class="button1"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Update</h1></a>
        <h1 class="button2"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-paypal"></i> Support the project</a></h1>
    <div>
</div>
```

And then created a center class and 2 different button classes.

```
.button1 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: #00B056;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button2 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.center{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This is the output:
https://leonisgeweldig.be/stackoverflow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both buttons same `width` and reduce the `font-size`

```css
.button1 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: #00B056;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.button2 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 210px);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <img height="100%" width="100%" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1254140/pexels-photo-1254140.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
      <p class="center">We're upgrading!</p>
      <div class="center">
          <a href="#"><h1 class="button1"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Update</h1></a>
          <h1 class="button2"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-paypal"></i> Support the project</a></h1>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a width and an align center to the classes:

```
.button1 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: #00B056;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.button2 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button1 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: #00B056;
    border-radius: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
a{text-decoration:none;}
.button2 {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.center{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="img/projectfly-logo.svg">
    <p class="center">We're upgrading!</p>
    <div class="center">
        <a href="#"><h1 class="button1"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Update</h1></a>
        <h1 class="button2"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-paypal"></i> Support the project</a></h1>
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid wrapping block level element with inline element.
- Also you can define common button class for both these buttons and add another 
  class which defines 
  background color to differentiate.
- so you can write HTML and css more semantic as:

```css
.button{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #00B056;
    border-radius: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .background-grey{
    background: grey
 }
 
 .center{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="center">We're upgrading!</p>
    <div class="center">
        <a href="#" class="button">
          <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
          <span> Update</span>
         </a>
        <a href="#" class="button background-grey">
          <i class="fab fa-paypal"></i>
          <span> Support the project<span>
         </a>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply give them same **width**.

```css
.button1,
.button2 {
  min-width: 250px !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.button1 {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  background-color: #00B056 !important;
  border-radius: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button2 {
  padding: 20px 60px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="center">We're upgrading!</p>
<div class="center">
  <a href="#">
    <h1 class="button1"><i class="fas fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update</h1>
  </a>
  <h1 class="button2"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-paypal" aria-hidden="true"></i> Support the project</a></h1>
  <div>
  </div>

</div>
<div>
```